# Problem Facing while reading data from the /dev/ttyUSB0

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, embedded

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

void main()
    {
    const char *device = "/dev/ttyUSB0"; // Replace with your USB TTL device name
    char buffer[10],buffer2[10];
    
    int spread,spwrite,serialPort_fd,input_fd,no_of_bytes_read = 0, written_bytes = 0,output_fd;
    
    serialPort_fd = open(device,O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    input_fd = open("input.txt",O_RDONLY);
    output_fd = open("output.txt",O_RDWR | O_CREAT);
    if(input_fd <= -1)
    {
        printf("Input file is not opened\n");
        return;
    }
    struct termios options;
    tcgetattr(serialPort_fd, &options);
    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200); // Set baud rate
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD); // Enable receiver and set local mode
    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // No parity
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; // 1 stop bit
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; // Mask the character size bits
    options.c_cflag |= CS8; // Set 8 data bits
    tcsetattr(serialPort_fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    
    no_of_bytes_read = read(input_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));// from input_fd to buffer
    //no_of_bytes_read = read(input_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
    printf("No of bytes read %d\n",no_of_bytes_read);
    written_bytes = write(serialPort_fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));//from buffer to serial_fd
    spread = read(serialPort_fd,buffer2,sizeof(buffer2));
    printf("buffer2 is %s\n",buffer2);
    close(serialPort_fd);
    close(input_fd);
    close(output_fd);
}
```

My requriment is read data from the input.txt(data = "hello") and send to output.txt via serialport(/dev/ttyUSB0),using Linux systemcall open(),read(),write(),close().
For now I am able to  write the data which I read from the input.txt into the serialprt(USB to tty converter) the problem I am facing is not able to read the data which in stored in the **SerialPort_fd** and store it into a buffer. Can you please help me with it.

**I have used a USB to tty converter and I have connected Rx and Tx pins together(Loopback)**

Comment: Have you got some kind of loopback connector, on your serial port? Have you connected the RX and TX pins together? If not, there should be no expectation that you can read back from a UART something you have written into it.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yeah I have used a loopback connector on my serial port. Is there any way where I can read the sent data into the serial port.Thansk for the help

Comment: `udelay((int)(no_of_bytes_read/(115200.0/10.0)*1000.0*1000.0)+100);`.  The write is buffered and you will read before the data is actually transmitted.  You can check the loopback connection with minicom to make sure it is working as well.  There are better solutions than just a delay, but this explains the issue.

Comment: Several issues with your code. (1) You neglect to check all but one return code. Any ignored error could explain "*not able to read the data*". (2) The serial terminal is opened for non-blocking I/O. The **write()** & **read()** could return before any data ever hits the wire. (3) The termios configuration is incomplete since you only configure basic line settings. FYI these line settings really don't matter with a loopback. But the other termios settings, e.g. canonical vs raw mode, are left to chance, and do affect **read()** behavior.

Comment: +1 upvote for posting a minimal, reproducible example of the problem that actually compiles without any errors.